# Connection to file-based hsql giving null

Tags: java, database, gradle, jdbc, hsqldb

I have problem about connecting through jdbc to my file-based hsqldb.
Here is my Dao class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class EventDao {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Applications/CreditTask/db";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASS = "";
    private Connection connection;

public EventDao() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        dropAndCreateTable();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void dropAndCreateTable() throws SQLException {
    final String dropSql = "drop table event";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(dropSql);
    preparedStatement.execute();
    final String createSql = "create table event(\n" +
            "    id int not null,\n" +
            "    state varchar(10) not null,\n" +
            "    timestamp int not null,\n" +
            "    type varchar(15),\n" +
            "    host varchar(15),\n" +
            "    alert boolean\n" +
            ")";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(createSql);
    preparedStatement.execute();
}

public void save(Event event) {
    final String sql = "insert into event(id,state,timestamp,type,host,alert) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, event.getId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, event.getState());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, event.getTimestamp().toString());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, event.getType());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, event.getHost());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, event.getAlert().toString());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And here is where i use it

```
public class EventParser {

private static final String FILE_NAME = "log.json";
private static final String STARTED = "STARTED";
private static final String FINISHED = "FINISHED";
private static final Long MAX_ALERT_RANGE = 4L;
private static final Logger logger
        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventParser.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventParser eventParser = new EventParser();
    eventParser.runApp();
}

public void runApp() {
    try {
        EventDao eventDao = new EventDao();
        logger.info("Reading events from file");
        Map<String, EventWrapper> eventsFromFile = readEventsFromFile();
        List<Event> eventsToSave = calculateEventTime(eventsFromFile);
        //2h in this state i didn't test saving to db using eventDao
        for (Event event : eventsToSave) {
            Runnable runnable = () -> eventDao.save(event);
            runnable.run();
        }
        eventDao.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//rest of the class are methods that giving me arrays of events
```

The problem is when i run this application im getting error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
at 

java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:332)
at event.EventDao.<init>(EventDao.java:19)
at event.EventParser.runApp(EventParser.java:32)
at event.EventParser.main(EventParser.java:27)
```

I read documentation and i check if i have downloaded the library but everything seems to be ok. Have You got any ideas why im getting null in the connection? Also there is any improvment in this app that i would not need to use drop and create table everytime i run application through dao constructor?

Answer (score 0):

When the call to `Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver")` throws the exception, it means the `hsqldb.jar` is not included in your classpath when your `java ...` command is executed.

Comment: I have it in external libraries. hsqldb-2.4.1.jar. Im using gradle with code like this `plugins {
    id 'java'
}`

`group 'CreditTask'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'`

`sourceCompatibility = 1.8`

`repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}`

`dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.8'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '2.4.1'
}`

Comment: The issue is with running your code, not building with gradle.

Comment: The issue was actually with gradle. I was using testCompile hsqldb and should be compile. After changes theere wasn't problem with driver and connection.